# Command line to delete folder in remote Windows from Linux host

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, remote-desktop

I use Linux and I have a remote Windows. I would like to try to delete folder in remote Windows (ex: C:\Temp) from my Linux by using command line.

My attempts are:

```
rm -rf IEUser@10.2.2.240/C/Temp

rm -rf //10.2.2.240/C/Temp
```

Both don't work, and I don't get any error.

Is is possible to delete folder in remote Windows by using command line? If yes, what would be the correct command line?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but: unlike Windows, there is no *automatic* network share setup in Linux. You need to:

- mount the share manually (as a `cifs` filesystem):

  ```
  # mount -t cifs //10.2.2.240/C /mnt/thatcomputer
  # rm -rf /mnt/thatcomputer/Temp
  ```
- or use the "smbclient" program:

  ```
  $ smbclient //10.2.2.240/C
  smb:\> deltree \Temp
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my knowledge of Linux is very little (i am new to Linux) :(. When you say _thatcomputer_, that means IP address of my Linux, right? So I tried:  `mount -t cifs //10.2.2.240/C /mnt/10.x.x.xxx`, but I get this message`mount: only root can use "--types" option`, and I am not root/admin so I can't either install smbclient

Comment: Then you might be out of luck. Do you have `gio` or `gvfs-mount`?

Comment: oh yes, I have `gvfs-mount`. I just tried `gvfs-mount //10.2.2.240/C/Temp`, but I got this message `Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount`

Comment: Note: C:\Temp is a folder I created everytime I run my automation test scripts on this remote Windows

Comment: Good, then use `gvfs-mount smb://10.2.2.240/C`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately, I got this message: `Error mounting location: Location is not mountable`

Comment: Maybe that means you have the gvfs core but not gvfs-smb, which again isn't fixable without administrator help.

Comment: yes what a pity. I will see about that. Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated